# Do I need to update destructive changes when removing a field translation metadata file?

Tags: translation-workbench, destructivechanges.xml, customobjecttranslation

If I am removing a field from an object and removing the corresponding `.fieldTranslation-meta.xml` file, do I need to add anything to the destructive changes post file?

I know that if I were removing the whole file, I would add something like:

```
<types>
    <members>Custom_Object__c-en_US</members>
    <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the field should delete the corresponding metadata (e.g. translations, field dependencies). There shouldn't be any need to explicitly include the translations as a separate item. If you wanted to be certain, though, you could do a "validate-only" deployment (check the online help for your chosen tool for directions on this); if you don't get a validation error, you're good to go.